# The background task in my SwiftUI app doesn't fire on physical device

Tags: ios, swift, scheduled-tasks, background-task, background-fetch

folks.
In my ios app with SwiftUI, I ma trying to implement fetch data in background in order to update my app with fresh data from the Back End. In order to do it, I am trying to implement it in the Background as you do, but it doesn't work on my iPad. It works fine on debugging with `e -l objc -- (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] _simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier:@"TASK_IDENTIFIER"]`.
I followed this article [Background tasks in SwiftUI](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2022/07/06/background-tasks-in-swiftui/) this one [New BackgroundTask in SwiftUI and How to Test It](https://holyswift.app/new-backgroundtask-in-swiftui-and-how-to-test-it/) and this [WWDC22 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10142/)

Here a steps I've made to implement it.

1. Added Background capability in **Target** -> **Signin && Capabilities** with **"Background fetch"** and **"Background processing"** being selected.
2. Then in **Info** I've added **"Permitted background task scheduler identifiers"** where I also added my task id.
3. I've created an async function where I schedule it, and I also thro notification in case there is an issue (This is only for testing..).

```
func sheduleBackgroundTask() async {
   
    let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "TASK_IDENTIFIER")
    request.earliestBeginDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 30, to: Date())
    do {
        try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        print("DEBUG: Background Task Scheduled!")
    } catch(let error) {
        print("DEBUG: Scheduling Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Background Task Failed!!!"
        content.subtitle = "Message: \(error.localizedDescription)"
        do{
            try await UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "NOTIFICATION_IDENTIFIER", content: content, trigger: UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)))
        } catch{
            print("DEBUG: Failed notify user \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        errorMessage = "Failed failed schedule background task. Message:  \(error.localizedDescription)"
    }
}
```

4. Then I have created a function where I fetch data from the server and save fetched data locally using Realm.
5. On apper I run configuration function for notifications and schedule background task.

```
    .onAppear{
              configurePushNotification()
              Task{
                await sheduleBackgroundTask()
              }
           }
```

6. Then I register my background task here.

```
 

.backgroundTask(.appRefresh("TASK_IDENTIFIER")) {
    await sheduleBackgroundTask()
    let _ = await refreshAppData()
 }
```

I've builded and uploaded my app on my iPad, left it for weekend, but without any changes.